# importing a final class in Java

Tags: java

I have declared this class:

```
public final class Constants {

     public static final String PROFILE_PCT__FILTER_NAME_ID = "profilePct";

}
```

I want to use that class in another class with..

```
import static com.tdk.utils.Constants.*;
```

But I got this compilation error:

> Constants cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Either: your package name is wrong (where you define Constants) or where you use it for the import.

Comment: Are you sure that package name is correct?  Maybe problem is in the class to which you want to import const?

Comment: Suggestion: rather than a vague class name like "Constants", which is just screaming to have loads of unrelated junk put in it, and suffixes to say what a particular constant is for, why not have specific (maybe nested) classes to say what it is: `class FilterNameIds { static final String PROFILE_PCT }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using the static import with `*`, you have access to the variables defined in the class. However, you can't refer to the class itself.

**Should work:-**

```
import static com.tdk.utils.Constants.*;
String  a =PROFILE_PCT__FILTER_NAME_ID;
```

**Shouldn't work:-**

```
String  a =Constants.PROFILE_PCT__FILTER_NAME_ID;
```

You need the below import to resolve the compilation issue.

```
import com.tdk.utils.Constants;
```